# JavaFx ImageView Set Center Image

Tags: javafx, imageview

I got little problem with ImageView to set image no-stretched and in center position. For ex i have ImageView with bounds 100px x 100px and i have about 50images with diffrent sizes but not bigger then 100x100. When i switching them on ImageView small ones are always stretched. When i use something like this :

```
 Image image = new Image(ImagePanel);
    this.ImageViewItem.setImage(image);
    Double h = image.getHeight();
    Double w = image.getWidth();

    ImageViewItem.setFitWidth(w);
    ImageViewItem.setFitHeight(h);
```

they are proper size but on left top corner.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question in [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919719/how-to-center-a-imageview-node-within-region-in-javafx). According to its reference we can use a StackPane, HBox, VBox, TilePane, FlowPane, BorderPane, GridPane, or AnchorPane.

For your problem you can use a Stackpane as follows.

```
 stackPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(img, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)));
```

In here your image won't get stretched and it will always align to the centre of the stackpane.